# How to get an IR sensor and motors to work together?

Tags: gpio

I've managed to connect a IR sensor to GPIO pin 23 and get LIRC to work with one of my remote controls. I've also set `irexec` up to launch a bash-script that drives motors (connected via open collectors):

```
#!/bin/bash

gpio -g mode 4 out
gpio -g mode 7 out

function forward {
        gpio -g write 4 1
        gpio -g write 7 1
}

function left {
        gpio -g write 4 0
        gpio -g write 7 1
}

function right {
        gpio -g write 4 1
        gpio -g write 7 0
}

function stop {
        gpio -g write 4 0
        gpio -g write 7 0
}

case $1 in
    "forward")
        forward
        ;;
    "left")
        left
        ;;
    "right")
        right
        ;;
    "stop")
        stop
        ;;
esac
```

Now, the problem is, after the first key press on the remote control, the motors start to spin but LIRC stops receiving any signals.

I assume writing to pins other than 23 causes the 23rd pin to be lost for lirc_rpi?

Comment: It sounds like electrical interference.  Lirc shouldn't care about what is happening on the other gpios.  How are you driving the motors?  Via a motor driver board or your own circuitry?

Comment: Nice to see you again @joan! The motors are connected to open collector ports on a Gertboard. The thing is, when I stop the motors running `./motors.sh stop` directly, the IR is still not working. I tried reloading the kernel module, to no avail. `mode2` reports silence.

Comment: Perhaps the script isn't returning control to Lirc.  Does Lirc still stop responding if you comment out the gpio -g calls or pass a parameter other than forward/left/right/stop?

Comment: @joan you might be right, I'll also try to launch the script with `&` in the end.

Comment: Nope, launching the script to background isn't helping.

Comment: I'd try to rule out interference, i.e. does Lirc keep working if you disconnect the motors but leave the software in place?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to read a character from keyboard like this.

```
#!/bin/bash
a=`stty -icanon ; dd bs=1 count=1 2>/dev/null`

gpio -g mode 4 out
gpio -g mode 7 out

function forward {
        gpio -g write 4 1
        gpio -g write 7 1
}

function left {

        gpio -g write 4 0
        gpio -g write 7 1
}

function right {

        gpio -g write 4 1
        gpio -g write 7 0
}

function stop {

        gpio -g write 4 0
        gpio -g write 7 0
}

case $a in

    "f")
        forward
        ;;

    "l")
        left
        ;;

    "r")
        right
        ;;

    "s")
        stop
        ;;

esac
```

I hope that help you